# django crispy forms - 'SubWidget' object has no attribute 'field'

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I created a model and modelform. I set up in settings the bootstrap3 template pack and put `crispy-forms` into installed_apps.

now, if I do:

```
{% crispy form %}
```

it shows the form like

```
label_name
<form.field>
..
etc etc.
```

but I want

```
label_name: <form.field>
```

in html.

if I do:

```
{% crispy form.fieldname %}
```

I am getting:

```
'SubWidget' object has no attribute 'field'
```

why? how can I control my form layout easily for this purpose?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `as_crispy_field` filter.

[Via the official documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_templatetags.html#templatetags.crispy_forms_filters.as_crispy_field):

```
templatetags.crispy_forms_filters.as_crispy_field(field, template_pack='bootstrap')[source]
Renders a form field like a django-crispy-forms field:

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{{ form.field|as_crispy_field }}
```

or:

```
{{ form.field|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}
```